# How to add additional custom parameters to enhanced event measurement (clicks) in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics-4

Can you add additional parameters to Google Analytics 4's built-in enhanced event measurement?

I want to include `link_text` and `link_category` parameters with a `click` event. I’ve used Google Tag Manager to set up GA4 but have enabled enhanced event measurement, so `click` events are already being tracked that way. I’ve tried adding a new GA4 event tag in GTM for a `click` event with these two additional parameters but it looks like it's tracking the event twice.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, you can't add additional parameters to automatically collected events.

---

**Workarounds**

1. **Turn off the automatically collected event in enhanced measurement settings** in your GA4 property and **manually trigger the event you want**, for eg, click event in this case. Then you can add all the extra parameters you want.
2. You can add some additional global parameters in `config` tag, those parameters will send with all the events triggered for that config's GA4 id. Sometimes this work if you want to send some page level information, however, you need to use it on a case/scenario basis.

Comment: Thank you @Tushar! That was my suspicion. The parameter I’d like to send is specific to the click event so it sounds like disabling automatic click tracking and setting up a new event tag in GTM will be the way to go.